# System Configuration for SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration

I need to identify the **system configuration for SharePoint server**, for the first phase We use it for DMS and considering to take more leverage on later stage. Currently DMS will be accessible internally

present workload is:

```
 150-200 users,
 3-5 GB space per user, 
 2 TB common shared storage.
```

I need suggestion from someone who had experienced with this size of requirement !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per you requirment you fall under the small farm, which is good upto 1000 users.

As per MSFT recomendation.

- Two Web Front end(Load Balance) and also act as App server for the services. All services and Websites on these server.
- One Dedicated DB server.

But as per My experince with zero fault tolerance, what we implemented.

- Two Web Front end(Load Balance)
- Two App Server for service i.e Search, UPA, Central admin etc
- dedicated SQL Server with Always-On solution.

Now its upto you which one is suite for you, if you dont have aggressive search in your farm then i would go with MSFT option.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/6/7/66777910-576E-4909-9A09-A12697881800/sps-2013-streamlined-topology-model.pdf

Comment: Thanks Waqas.  Should I go with MSFT recommendation in case of RAM and CPU size !!

Comment: they are pretty much standard and i would go with them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a 2 server farm. One server is to be used as WFE role and Second server can be used as APP Server & DB Server.

Both Servers can use 8 Core CPU and 16 GB RAM.

Hard Disk space needs to be allocated more on the Second server because that is where all the user data will get stored.

Comment: Thanks Amal .... but is it ok(in case of performance) to put App and DB in same server !!

Comment: for performance stands point, it is never recommended to have SharePoint on sql server in production.

Comment: Your user count is less. So i dont see much performance issues. This is the exact setup I implemented for my client who had 300 users. Also you have the flexibility to add more servers on the go.